# What is the state of "artifical photosynthesis" technology, as at March 2014?

Tags: solar-power

I've been hearing a lot in the news about artificial photosynthesis processes that can use energy from sunlight to split water and produce synthetic fuel. Sounds pretty exciting, but being a non-physicist, I'm having some trouble separating the science from the hype. So I'm hoping somebody can set me straight.

- Does this technology exist in any form at anything beyond a proof-of-concept stage?
- Is it possible, at the present time, to produce renewable fuel in a sustainable/environmentally friendly way (i.e. one that doesn't require the use of scarce, toxic catalysts?) I've heard the term "solar fuel" tossed around, but I'm not clear on what that means: Hydrogen? Methanol? Something else?
- Would this offer any advantages over just using batteries/fuel cells to store the electricity produced by PV systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Joint Centre for Artificial Photosynthesis](http://solarfuelshub.org/) (JCAP), research is ongoing.  Very recently, according to the JCAP's News and Events page, [researchers have been researching and testing](http://today.lbl.gov/2014/02/18/presentation-award-for-jcap-postdoc-at-photosynthesis-conference/)

> energetics and efficiency analysis of a material capable of harnessing solar energy into fuel.

In general, the stages that JCAP appears to be at, according to their [research page](http://solarfuelshub.org/research/)

> spans efforts ranging from the fundamental discovery of new light absorbing materials to the design and testing of fully functional prototypes.

where the prototyping is focussed on

> the design of prototype models that use dual-light absorber (tandem) configuration cells.

A list of their research is [on their publications page](http://solarfuelshub.org/research/publications.html).

In terms of what solar fuels are, the Royal Society of Chemistry article [Solar Fuels](http://www.rsc.org/ScienceAndTechnology/Policy/Documents/solar-fuels.asp) illustrates the process as well as defining 'solar fuels' as being hydrogen gas, methane, carbon monoxide and methanol - these are used in both industrial processes as well as generating electricity:

[image]

Several infographics are also provided by the Royal Society of Chemistry's page [Solar fuels and artificial photosynthesis](http://www.rsc.org/ScienceAndTechnology/Policy/Documents/solar-fuels-production-infographics.asp) (an example is above).

Some benefits of artificial photosynthesis is, according to the article [The Promise of Artificial Photosynthesis](http://www.energybiosciencesinstitute.org/sites/default/files/upload/2013winter_Photosynthesis.pdf), include that while PV cells can produce electricity, artificial photosynthesis can also provide fuels and industrial chemicals (as seen in the diagram above).

Comment: If the produce is hydrogen and hydrocarbon fuels, why not just use old boring electrolysis coupled with solar panels?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might've heard of the progress of a Santa Barbara, CA company called HyperSolar and their photosynthesis-inspired design for an underwater electrolysis application of nano-scale electrodes that are mass produced from copper or copper-coated material (or something like that).  Fantastic technology, if it ever gets to market....

Here they are:

http://www.hypersolar.com/

Enjoy!  :)

Answer (score 1):

The Naval Research Lab has also done some interesting work on extracting CO2 and water from seawater and fabricating fuel from that: http://www.nrl.navy.mil/media/news-releases/2012/fueling-the-fleet-navy-looks-to-the-seas